# Why login and session id is not being set in this function?

Tags: php, mysql, sessionid

I am  try to  loggin in and setting the session id.Below code did not authenticate the login successfully and did not set the session id.Plz help.

```
  public $userid;

  function login()
    {
        $pwdHasher = new PasswordHash(8, FALSE);

        if(isset($_POST['logging'])  AND  !empty($_POST['logging'])){


            $email=mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->connection ,$_POST['email']);
            $pass=mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->connection ,$_POST['pass']);
            $sql=mysqli_query($this->db->connection,"SELECT * FROM user where email='$email' AND password='$pass'");
            $numrows=mysqli_num_rows($sql);
            $resid=mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
            $checked = $pwdHasher->CheckPassword($pass,$numrows);
            if($checked){
                $this->userid=$_SESSION['id']=$resid['id'];

                $this->login=TRUE;


                echo "u r logedin.Plz click here to go  to main area<a href='main.php'>main</a>";
            }
            else{
                echo "username r password is wrong";
                $this->login=FALSE;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use session_start() before using $_SESSION.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start a session with `session_start()` before using the $_SESSION array

Answer (score 0):

you might be missing the `session_start()` at the beginning of the PHP script.  if you have a common file that you include in every single file then simply add `session_start()` to the very beginning.

If you do not have a common file and it would be too hard to add one, you can modify the `php.ini` file to have `session.auto_start` to start the session for you.

If you cannot access the `php.ini` file and you are using apache as web server then you can modify/add the `.htaccess` file to the root of your `DOCUMENT_ROOT` by adding: `php_flag session.auto_start 1`

take a look at those links, they might help you understand better the sessions and figure out why it is not working

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start